# Compute the distributional limit

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi i started complex analysis a few weeks back and we have arrived at distributions. In my case distributional limits. There was this exercise that was solved and i understood all the steps except for the last one. The exercise goes like this:

Compute the distributional limit of $T_n=e^x\delta(x-log(n))$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}  = \langle(e^x\delta(x-log(n)),\phi\rangle $ =

$\lim_{n \to \infty}  = \langle(\delta(x-log(n)),e^x\phi\rangle$ =

$\lim_{n \to \infty}  = e^{(log(n)}\phi(log(n))$=

$\lim_{n \to \infty}  = n\phi(log(n))$ = 0

Now what i dont understand is the last part

$\lim_{n \to \infty}  = n\phi(log(n))$ = 0 Why is it equal to 0?

Comment: In some settings one considers test functions $\phi$ with compact support, so when $n$ is large, $\log n$ will lie outside the support of $\phi$.

Comment: @angryavian And now i want to punch myself! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

$\phi$ is usually assumed to have compact support, so if $n$ is large then $\phi(\log(n))=0$. Hence, the limit is also 0.